# RedirectToAction in class - How do I this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I put my RedirectToAction into a Claas, I've tried to do it like this.

```
public static void UserOnlineNow()
    {
        int brugeridValue = Helper.BrugerInformation.SessionVale.SessionBrugerid();
        DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
        var bruger = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == brugeridValue);
        if (bruger != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "account");
        }
    }
```

i have try its here:

```
HttpContext.Current
```

before *RedirectToAction*

The reason I need to use it in a class is the very reason that I will not write it too many places around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` is defined in the base `Controller` class (which normal controllers are inherited from) and you should be using that in your controllers.

If you are worried about doing this code in so many places, you should consider writing an action filter and apply that to your controller/action methods.

```
public class OnlineUserCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool burgerExists = false;
        //check your table and set the burgerExists variable value.
        //burgerExists=db.brugeres.Any(s=>s.Id==3453); // replace hard coded value
        if (burgerExists)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                     new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"controller", "Inspection"}, {"action", "Index"}
                    }
                );
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And you can decorate the action methods with this action filter.

```
[OnlineUserCheck]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes it's true, but the way you wrote it to give me an idea of how in an easy and smart way only build it up into the controller.

Comment: Thanks for help. i will giv u +1 for its help, and i will hop u giv mig a +1 for its questions