# MVC Redirect based on Controller action in Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i am trying to add a controller to my layout that can redirect from the page based on some condition. Wondering what is the best approach.  my Layout is something like this

```
<body class="body">
@Html.Action("IsPageNeedsRedirection", "Authentication", new { area = string.Empty })
@Html.Partial("Header", Model)
@Html.Partial("Body", Model)
</body>
```

Then my controller for Authentication looks like this :

```
 public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult IsPageNeedsRedirection()
        {
            var urlToRedirect= '/login';
            var isAuthenticationRequired = // Get t/f based on current page to know if it requries authentication; 
            if (isAuthenticationRequired && !isLoggedIn){
            return Redirect(urlToRedirect);
            }
            else {return null;}
        }
    }
```

This is not working because

- if the condition is true redirection fails and get an exception **"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions"** (which makes sense because the view is ready to be rendered already)
- if the condition is false, still throws an exception.

What would be the ideal way to handle such authentication redirects?  this happens for only some pages and i unless i know what page, i wont know if the page needs authentication or not.

Comment: Consider an action filter ? No need to execute all the action code/view parsing code

Comment: Its not really clear what you are trying to do here. Why are you not using an `[Authorize]` attribute on your methods so you are automatically redirected to the login method

Comment: @StephenMuecke I cant use Authorize because in reality - i am using a CMS and only few pages needs authentication. Only after i resolve the page (in the Auth controller) i get the value for the flag isAuthenticationRequired

Comment: Then use a custom action filter as @Shyju suggested (or in the relevant controller methods, call a service that returns your `isAuthenticationRequired` value, and if so, make the redirect in the controller method)

Comment: Here is a sample action filter for your reference. Make changes to the logic as needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426680/redirecttoaction-in-class-how-do-i-this  You can register the filter globally or apply to specific controllers or actions.